# Newest version of Forge v1.4.49 windows IOS app crashes

Tags: ios, crash, trigger.io

With the newest version of forge v1.4.49 when I try and test my IOS app from my windows comp the app installs but when I open it crashes.

I also tested using testFlight and get the same error. ( I get no error message as the console does not work in windows for debug, it just opens and then closes when I try and run the app )

I put the version back to version 1.4.48 and it works fine so I'm guessing it is something introduced in the newest version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** This is due to cross-platform line ending issues in the Python standard library: we deployed a fix on 18th July '13 which will fix all deployed platform versions.

---

**Original answer:**

The only iOS change that went into v1.4.49 was reading app entitlements information from your provisioning profile, rather than inferring it from active modules.

I'd recommend using the [iPhone configuration utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466) to get the console output off the device: you may see a message about incorrect entitlements.

If the particular message doesn't help clear this up for you, get in touch at support@trigger.io, with your IPA and provisioning profile for us to check over.

Comment: Thanks James, let me give this a shot when I get back to the office. I was unaware of the iphone configuration util I will have to give this ago. Ill update the post when I test it out.

Comment: Hi James, I gave this a shot and it still does not work, I'm getting a strange kill: 9 error that from what I can tell is a memory issue? Again the strange thing is that this works just fine with version 1.4.8